# Trouble enabling the SSL connection between a Java application and a MySQL instance

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, amazon-rds

I am having trouble enabling the SSL/TLS connection between a Java application and a MySQL instance.

The following warning message is present in the logs of my Java application:

```
WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

**Initial situation:**

My MySQL database is hosted on AWS RDS. In the AWS Console, the database's Certificate Authority is listed as "rds-ca-2019." According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), this Certificate Authority provides certificates included in both the regional and global certificate bundles. I've utilized both the appropriate regional bundle in .pem format and the corresponding global bundle in .pem format. The application is running on Java 17 and establishes connections using a jdbc URL. The MySQL version is 5.7.42.

**Attempt 1:**

I built the jdbc URL like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://<dns_name>:3306/<db_name>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=true&amp;sslMode=VERIFY_IDENTITY&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file%3A%2Fetc%2Fssl%2Fcerts
```

as trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl I used the default folder for certificates in Debian systems `/etc/ssl/certs`. There I put the just mentioned bundles and set the permissions with chmod to 644.

**Attempt 2**

I created my own truststore.jks with keytool and imported the two official AWS certificate bundles there with keytool as well and adjusted the jdbc URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://<dns_name>:3306/<db_name>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&sslMode=VERIFY_IDENTITY&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file%3A%2Fetc%2Fssl%2Fcerts%2Ftruststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=<my_pass>
```

Unfortunately, that couldn't solve the problem either and I still get the warning.

**Attempt 3:**

I found out that Java has a default truststore, which is apparently used if you don't specify one in the jdbc URL. It is linked as symbolic link under `/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts` to `/etc/ssl/certs/adoptium/cacerts`. There I imported again the regional and global certificate bundle with keytool. Still with warning messages...

**Attempt 4:**

I enabled SSL debug logs when running the .jar and the logs did not help me:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.371 CEST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = ...
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.381 CEST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry =  ChaCha20-Poly1305 KeyUpdate 2^37. CHACHA20-POLY1305:KEYUPDATE = ...
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.654 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.655 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.656 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.657 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.657 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.658 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.658 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.659 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.659 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.660 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.660 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.661 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.661 CEST|X509Authentication.java:249|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.810 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1334|Closing output stream
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.811 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:577|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.812 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1759|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.813 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1785|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.813 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:837|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.816 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:595|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details: (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1601)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:219)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:853)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:802)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:664)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:584)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:1338)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.close(PGStream.java:738)
        at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutorBase.close(QueryExecutorBase.java:156)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.close(PgConnection.java:749)
        at com.dtad.dtad_content_indexer.Indexer.initGeoMapper(Indexer.java:130)
        at com.dtad.dtad_content_indexer.Indexer.<init>(Indexer.java:48)
        at com.dtad.dtad_content_indexer.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:56)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-10-18 14:12:55.817 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1139|Closing input stream
```

I hope someone can help me troubleshoot this, as I have already made several attempts that did not work. I'm also not entirely certain whether the issue is related to the truststore or if it's caused by something else.

Thanks in advance!